# Geometry Nodes: Reflected RayCast (Camera Culling with Reflections)

Tags: geometry-nodes, reflection

I want to compute second ray to distribute my points for reflection surfaces
(Somehow solve camera culling problem for reflections, when you cant see scattered trees/grass on glasses with camera culling)
Im using the vector reflect node, but it doesn't work

[Camera Culling with Reflections.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/95c2640c9b0642428fc1dac2a9732767)

[image]